# Can I get 2 separate word on one regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation, regex-greedy

**Sample text:**

> Code= go to 65416541654 name **DHANA** for 1 period JUL 2021 SN Hrg=314800 Bill=313500 Admin=2500 **Total Bill=316000** check Bill SUCCESS. Balance=835606.

I need to extract **Name DHANA** and **Total Bill=316000**. Could I do that using single regex?

My regex now is

```
/(name)( | :|:|=| =)(?P<sn>(.*?))(check bill)/i
```

But with this regex I capture other things that I didn't even need.

```
DHANA for 1 period JUL 2021 SN Hrg=314800 Bill=313500 Admin=2500 Total Bill=316000
```

So can I just capture only NAME and the Total Bill alone without period and anything between?

More info
- The name can be more than one word Example Dhana Merdeka
- if possible i need the captured SN will show `DHANA MERDEKA Total Bill=316000` or `DHANA Total Bill=316000` (if the name only one word)

Comment: Can the name consist of more than one word?

Comment: `(?:name \w+|Total Bill=\d+)` - This is extracting what you want.

Comment: @AKSingh sorry i too dumb on regex, thanks for your help. but where i should put that 
`(?:name \w+|Total Bill=\d+)` ?? 
and is that possible to still use SN because i need anything captured as sn so i can show it on user panel. 

when i check your code. the first name only captured. the last name isn't. example if the name Dhana Merdeka. only Dhana that captured... i need it captured all the name and the total bill only. ummm can i do that?

Comment: @AKSingh and yeah. the name can consist more than one word.

Comment: You can use 2 capture groups `\b(name .+?) for \d+ period .*? (Total Bill=\d+)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/1Dv1M4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird umm is that possible to make it on one capture groups? so i didn't need to edit the entire php?
Example i use current (?P<sn>(.*?)) so all capture group belong to SN?

Comment: You can use it like this to get matches only `\bname .+?(?= for \d)|Total Bill=\d+\b` https://regex101.com/r/xxIFvt/1But note that now it matches in any order. Or in php allowing duplicate subpattern names using `/J` like for example `(?P<SN>\bname .+?(?= for \d))|(?P<SN>Total Bill=\d+\b)` https://regex101.com/r/hK0pho/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird oke, but but. is this the last way to get rid of it? i mean, we can only make 2 group and allow it to be duplicate? and make php to allow it get all of two group? or there's other way to get two of it on one SN?

like... deleting/ignore all of the character other than name and the total bill?

Comment: You are using php right? What prevents you from getting the values of the capture groups? Does it have to be only group SN? Can you modify the cod3?

Comment: @Thefourthbird well basicly, i use some script that using php. but for Regex there's already some box where i can write down the regex. and on that when i adding /gmJ it doesn't work for G (Global) so that's why i so confuse how i implemented that... that's why i asking is that possible to use `/(name)( | :|:|=| =)(?P<sn>(.*?))(check bill)/i`
or anything like that which have single sn to extract the result. and delete or ignore anything between